# Is there a program that can help us to solve 2D bin packing problem with multiple bin (variable size)?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, pulp, bin-packing, operations-research

I'm trying to make a program on solving the 2 dimensional variable sized bin packing problem.

The case is i have N amount of box, each has its own size.
M amount of bins, each with its own size.

i want to fit all the box into those bins so that the waste of space and amount of bins being used is minimized. (rotation also considered but limited to 90 degrees).

is there any program that can solve this? thanks!

I already tried using Pulp but it does seems like my model is wrong